# Read a sequence of ints from cin and store them in a vector

Tags: c++

This is what I have done to read integers with `std::cin` and store them in a vector:

```
int number; 
vector<int>ivec;

while (cin>>number)
{       
    ivec.push_back(number);
}

for (auto v: ivec){

    cout << v;
}
```

Then, I am stuck with the problem that how to stop entering integers and move to the next process of printing the vector out. Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: Prompt the user how many numbers are being entered and then loop that many times, or prompt the user after each number is entered to see if they want to enter another number, or have them enter just about anything that is not a number so `cin` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted reads numbers from `cin` as long as it succeeds. There are two ways to have it stop succeeding: If you enter something that is not a number, reading data still succeeds, but converting it to number fails. This puts `cin` into the *bad* state. It can be recovered from using the `clear` methode. The other way is making the reading of characters from `cin` fail (for example the end of a file that gets used as input). This puts `cin` into the `failed` state. Usually, recovering from a failed state is impossible.

To produce the *you can no longer read* state at end of file when entering data at the keyboard, operating system specific methods have to be used (likely Control-D or Control-Z). This is final for the invocation of your program.

If you need a way for the user to signal: "Please go on, but let me enter other stuff later", the most clean way is likely reading `cin` line-by-line and parse the input using `strtol` or a `stringstream`, and comparing for a magic stop-token (e.g. empty line, "end") to exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the terminal in use and the precise mechanism varies quite a lot but, conventionally, typing Ctrl+D (Linux) or Ctrl+Z (Windows) will result in an end-of-file "signal" being transmitted along the pipe, causing the EOF bit to be set on `cin`, and thus the next `cin >> number` attempt to fail.

That will break the loop.

Conveniently, the same will happen if you ran your executable with redirected input from a file. Which is kind of the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

//...

vector<int> ivec( std::istream_iterator<int>( std::cin ), 
                  std::istream_iterator<int>() );


for ( auto v: ivec ) std::cout << v << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

In Windows you have to press key combination `Ctrl + z` and in UNIX system `Ctrl + d`

Or you can introduce a sentinel. In this case the loop can look like

```
int number; 

const int sentinel = SOME_VALUE;

for ( std::cin >> number && number != sentinel ) vec.push_back( number );
```

Comment: That is a nicer way of re-writing the `while` loop, but that does not solve the actual issue of how to stop the iteration so the second loop can run.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The vector constructor does (mostly?) what the loop in the original question did too.

Answer (score 0):

Please find a simple solution to your problem, let me know if you see any issue with this solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> va;
    int x;
    while ( cin >> x ) {
          va.push_back(x);
          if ( cin.get() == '\n' ) break;
    }
    //Vector output
    for ( int i = 0; i < va.size(); i++ ) {
        cout << va[i] <<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```